# UIDocumentPickerViewController: Open folder from Dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

How can I use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to let the user select a *folder* from their Dropbox?

If I call this, I can browse for folders, but the Dropbox folder is greyed out:

```
[[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeFolder]
                                                       inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
```

If I change the mode to `UIDocumentPickerModeImport`, I get an Assertion failure and it crashes. It seems that `Import` doesn't work together with `kUTTypeFolder`. If I keep `Import` and set the types to `@[kUTTypeFolder, kUTTypeImage]`, I get access to the Dropbox, but the picker only lets me select images, not folders.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dropbox iOS app document picker doesn't support opening folders, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

Comment: Thanks Greg! It would be really useful for importing a lot of files at once.

Comment: Hi Greg, any change in 2021? Or should I go for Dropbox API if I need folder access?

Comment: @IvanMir I don't have an update on this request unfortunately, so I do recommend using the API if the current doc picker support doesn't satisfy your use case.