# Third-party storage inaccessible when DocumentPicker initialized with "public.folder" documentTypes

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, onedrive, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am writing an iOS plugin for Unity in Objective-C. I have created a DocumentPicker which allows me to select Folders. However, it does not seem to have access to Third-party storage (such as OneDrive, DropBox, etc).

I am certain I have the permissions for this, because I have also created a DocumentPicker within the same Application which allows me to select Zip files; the Zip file DocumentPicker has no problem browsing these third-party storage areas.

Here is how I am declaring the DocumentPicker instance for Folder selection:

```
[[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.folder"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
```

Likewise, here is the fully-functioning declaration for the Zip file selection:

```
[[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.zip-archive"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

[Here is a screencapture of inaccessible Third-party storage in grey, while local storage and iCloud remain accessible in white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI7GX.png)

I thought perhaps Microsoft, Google, etc, haven't implemented a Document Provider extension for Folder selection, but that seems a bit of a stretch.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361941/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-open-folder-from-dropbox) it is not implemented by Dropbox, so one could assume this is the same issue with OneDrive, etc.